# combine two ajax functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

ok i have this:

```
/******AJAX SUBPAGES ACADEMIES****/
coachesLinks.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
coachesLinks.click(function (e) {
            var $el = jQuery(this);
            var URL = $el.attr('href');
            var URL = URL + " .main";
    jQuery(contentTwo).show('slow').load(URL, function () {
        scrollToAnchor('content_two');
        ajaxloader('.academy_coaches_readmore');
        accordion();
        $('.main').css('overflow', 'visible');
        $(contentTwo).css('overflow', 'visible');
        jQuery('#content_two .back').on('click', function () {
            jQuery(this).hide('slow');
            if (contentTwo.is(':hidden')) {
                jQuery('#content_two .back').hide();
            } else {
                contentTwo.hide('slow');
                jQuery(contentmain).show('slow');
                jQuery(contentmain).css('overflow', 'visible');
                scrollToAnchor('access');
            }
        });

    });
    $(contentmain).hide('slow');
});
```

and this:

```
function ajaxloader(myselector) {
        internalLinks = jQuery(myselector);
        internalLinks.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        internalLinks.click(function (e) {
            var $el = jQuery(this);
            var URL = $el.attr('href');
            var URL = URL + " .main";
            jQuery(contentTwo).show('slow').load(URL, function () {
                scrollToAnchor('content_two');
                $('.main').css('overflow', 'visible');
                $(contentTwo).css('overflow', 'visible');
                jQuery('#content_two .back').on('click', function () {
                    jQuery(this).hide('slow');

                    if (contentTwo.is(':hidden')) {
                        jQuery(contenttwoback).hide();
                    } else {
                        contentTwo.hide('slow');
                        jQuery(contentmain).show('slow');
                        jQuery(contentmain).css('overflow', 'visible').delay(100);
                        scrollToAnchor('access');

                    }
                });

            });
            $(contenttwoback).show('slow');
            $(contentmain).hide('slow');
        });
}
```

with these variables:

```
/******variables******************/
            var contentmain = jQuery('#content > .main');
            var contentTwo = jQuery('#content_two');
            var siteURL = 'http://' + top.location.host.toString();
            var coachesLinks = jQuery(' .academy_readmore');
```

I'm calling the second function like so:

```
/******AJAX SUBPAGES SUBMENU FUNCTION****/
ajaxloader('#submenunav ul li a');
/******AJAX SUBPAGES COACHES****/
ajaxloader('#accordion .coaches_readmore');
/******AJAX LESSONS***/
ajaxloader('#accordion .lessons_readmore');
```

Which works perfectly my question is how do i call the second function with the nested ajax as a parameter?
something like this (which doesn't work):

```
 ajaxloader('#accordion .lessons_readmore' ajaxloader('.academy_coaches_readmore'));
```

Nesting the second ajax load inside of the first ajax loader?? 
Chris
full copy of the code here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/JGVEb/

Comment: ok rather than just downvoting could you please provide some feedback as to what is wrong with the question I'm trying to imrpove my code and understand how to pass a function as a function parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want these AJAX requests to be performed in serial, such that the second one happens only after the first one completes?

You can supply a callback function as a parameter in your function.  Something like this:

```
function ajaxloader(myselector, callback) {
    // some code
    jQuery(contentTwo).show('slow').load(URL, function () {
        // more code

        if (callback) { callback(); }
    });
};
```

That way it will invoke the callback after it's finished with the AJAX request.  You'd then invoke it like any other jQuery function that has a callback:

```
ajaxloader('#accordion .lessons_readmore', function () {
    ajaxloader('.academy_coaches_readmore'));
});
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean I have tried to implement it but the call back efuses to apply the ajax to the second load, my problem here is that i have ajax loading a page that then has a link which i want to load with ajax again... 
new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JGVEb/1/

Comment: @vimes1984: It's really not clear what the problem is.  And that jsFiddle doesn't actually demonstrate anything.  Perhaps you can remove unrelated code and provide a minimal working example of just the issue at hand?

Comment: I've fixed it... Basically was i was trying to accomplish is the following: 
User lands on page A clicks submenu.
Submenu loads page B via ajax onto current page. 
Page B contains another submenu to load page C ( here's where i was trying to write the first function to take the page C ajaxload function as a parameter. 
I've fixed by doing the following: 
Adding page B ajax function into the call back on ajaxloader();
like so http://jsfiddle.net/JGVEb/2/ is there any inconviniance with doing this calling the function from inside the function??

Comment: @vimes1984: There shouldn't be, unless you're doing something very wrong which I can't see from here.  Nesting functions as callbacks is very common.

Comment: even if the function being nested is inside of the function initself, It seems counterintuitive how can i use the function inside of it's self?
this screams to me not to work: 
function A(){
blahblah.('click', function(){
a();
});
}

Comment: @vimes1984: It's really not clear what you mean.  Functions can call themselves, that's how recursion works.  You'd just need to make sure that they don't *infinitely* call themselves without any terminating condition.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38273/discussion-between-vimes1984-and-david)